# avrdude: can't handle ELF file checkio.hex, ELF file support was not compiled in

Tags: c, debian, embedded, avr, toolchain

I am looking for someone who guide me to solve the below error in AVR Micro controller (OS:Debian 32 bit) .

```
/* checkio.c*/
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#endif
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#include<avr/fuse.h>
int main()
{
  DDRA=0xFF;

  PORTA=0;
  while(1)
  {
       PORTA=0xFF;
       _delay_ms(1000);

        PORTA=0;
       _delay_ms(1000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

AND related make file is :

```
CFLAGS1=-g -mmcu=atmega32 -c
CFLAGS2=-g -mmcu=atmega32 -o
GFLAGS3=-j .text -j .data ihex

checkio.hex:checkio.elf
    avr-objcopy $(CFLAGS3) checkio.elf checkio.hex
checkio.elf:checkio.o
    avr-gcc $(CFLAGS2) checkio.elf checkio.o
checkio.o:checkio.c
    avr-gcc $(CFLAGS1) checkio.c

burn:   
    sudo /home/poonam/proj_utility/avr_dude/install/bin/avrdude -p atmega32 -P /dev/bus/usb/002/004 -c usbasp -u -U flash:w:checkio.hex
clean:
    rm *.elf *.hex *.o
```

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9502

avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.

avrdude: erasing chip

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware 
update.

avrdude: reading input file "checkio.hex"

avrdude: input file checkio.hex auto detected as ELF

avrdude: can't handle ELF file checkio.hex, ELF file support was not compiled in

avrdude: read from file 'checkio.hex' failed

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Comment: Typo: You've set the variable `GFLAGS3`, but you reference `CFLAGS3` in the rule. (Personally, I'd just call it `AVRDUDE_OPTS`.)

Comment: The objcopy command uses `CFLAGS3`, but that is not defined.  You have defined `GFLAGS3` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is not that avrdude cannot handle elf files, but rather that your .hex file is an elf file rather then a hex file in the first instance.

Your objcopy command should specify the output file format:

```
avr-objcopy -O ihex checkio.elf checkio.hex
            ^^^^^^^
```

Perhaps the apparent typo: `GFLAGS3` instead of `CFLAGS3` is the cause of this, but you still need the `-O ihex` rather then just `ihex`:

```
CFLAGS3=-j .text -j .data -O ihex

checkio.hex:checkio.elf
    avr-objcopy $(CFLAGS3) checkio.elf checkio.hex
```